# Incorrect numbers in Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

In the current monthly Reputation Leagues, one user has more monthly reputation than total. Could this be a counting error or is this an issue because an inconsistency in caching or the methods of calculating reputation?

[image: user with more monthly reputation than total]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

---

The week, month and year reputation contains reputation **from deleted posts too** but the total reputation won't include it.

If you want another example of it, here is mine

[image]