# Reputation league does not take daily reputation limit into account for deleted posts

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-leagues, deleted-posts

The [reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/month/meta) is looking a little weird right now; the #1 spot for October is occupied by a [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/316129/don-thermidor-lobster-mobster) with 5,352 reputation gained this month (according to the league) but only 1,077 reputation:

[image]

This is caused by deleted posts; see [Incorrect numbers in Reputation Leagues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298366/295232). In this particular case, [this +478 answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/334979#334979) [(screenshot for users with less than 10k reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGXiX.png)) was deleted, and it seems that *all upvotes* on that answer are counted, disregarding the fact that most of them (all but ~80) wouldn't have counted anyway, because of the [daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day). It does make sense to include [private reputation events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/295232) in the leagues but it would be nice to have them count for the right amount of reputation.

Comment: Personally, I'll be quite upset if a CM or representative, while ignoring every single issue that has been front page news on MSE in the last three weeks, replies to this. There are worst *bugs* to fix.

Comment: Oh, it's a low-priority bug for sure. And I could imagine that there are some Stack Exchange developers who only handle 'technical' issues and don't want to burn their hands on the CoC situation (and I wouldn't blame them for it).

Comment: Just to know. Why that answer was deleted? If it was from a mod or CM? Was there a good reason for that?

Comment: A CM has stated "I'm deleting this because it is impractical to answer a dozen questions asked at once, and meanwhile this has become a perpetual target for warring in comments."

Comment: Let me guess. It became a perpetual target for warring in comments because nobody else was agreeing with the CM. Did I got it right?