# Mismatch between the top users in the Stack Exchange league and period wise report pages

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

In the [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) page, there are some mismatches between the display in the main page and the period-wise report page.

For example in the Stack Overflow League, the top user for the month is unutbu and the top user for the quarter is Ciro Santilli, but clicking on the [month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) and [quarter](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow) pages, the top user is listed as Gordon Linoff.

> [image: SO League]

Likewise, in the Meta Stack Exchange League the top user for the quarter is displayed as Glorfindel, but clicking on the [quarter](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/quarter/meta) page the top user is listed as Sterling Archer:

> [image: MSE League]

Is this a bug or known functonality?

Comment: Ha, this is funny, I wasn't ware of that page. Definitely, can't beat Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a bug, but the [Leagues overview page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) shows the same top users (up to caching) as the /users page on the site itself:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week (Gordon Linoff is 2nd, a few points behind jezrael)
- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month (unutbu is the top user)
- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter (Ciro Santilli is the top user)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week (GhostCat is 2nd, a few points behind Monica)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month (heather is the top user)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter (I'm the top user)

The [league itself](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/quarter/meta) includes [reputation from deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298366/295232), and worse, the [daily reputation limit isn't (at least not entirely) taken into account for those posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335517/295232).